# Scrapy crashes (wont run) on basic example

Tags: python, crash, scrapy

Im using Python 2.7 (Anaconda) on Windows 7 x64. I installed Scrapy via pip. The version installed is 1.0.1. I am trying to run the basic example in the [tutorial](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/overview.html) i.e.:

```
import scrapy


class StackOverflowSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'stackoverflow'
    start_urls = ['http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes']

    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.css('.question-summary h3 a::attr(href)'):
            full_url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
            yield scrapy.Request(full_url, callback=self.parse_question)

    def parse_question(self, response):
        yield {
            'title': response.css('h1 a::text').extract()[0],
            'votes': response.css('.question .vote-count-post::text').extract()[0],
            'body': response.css('.question .post-text').extract()[0],
            'tags': response.css('.question .post-tag::text').extract(),
            'link': response.url,
        }
```

And then at the command line:

```
scrapy runspider stackoverflow_spider.py -o top-stackoverflow-questions.json
```

However Python crashes before doing anything. Windows reports:

> python.exe has stopped working

The only output in the command prompt I get is:

```
C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scrapy\commands\deploy.py:16: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Module `scrapy.command` is deprecated, use`scrapy.commands` instead
  from scrapy.command import ScrapyCommand
2015-07-17 16:39:28 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.1 started (bot: scrapybot)
2015-07-17 16:39:28 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11, boto
2015-07-17 16:39:28 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'FEED_FORMAT': 'json','FEED_URI': 'top-stackoverflow-questions.json'}
```

Does anyone know how to get Scrapy working? Have I installed it incorrectly?

---

Following from @Amol answer, I have uninstalled Scrapy using pip and then removed all folders from the Python/Anconda package directory. Then reinstalled using pip. The same problem persists but the first line of the output before it crashes has gone. The output now is:

```
2015-07-17 16:39:28 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.1 started (bot: scrapybot)
2015-07-17 16:39:28 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11, boto
2015-07-17 16:39:28 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'FEED_FORMAT': 'json','FEED_URI': 'top-stackoverflow-questions.json'}
```

Comment: It works for me. Also, why don't use stackexchange api instead of web-scraping?

Comment: @alecxe i dont want to scrap stackexchange its just the example in the tutorial. what os/set-up are you using?

Comment: Mac, Python 2.7, Scrapy 1.0.1. No errors, runs and extracts 50 items, makes 51 requests.

Comment: Maybe it is something to do with anaconda? Try another interpreter implementation maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure it out. So uninsulated Python and reinstalled it and now scrapy works. Not ideal though

Answer (score 1):

*scrapy\commands\deploy.py* file should not be present for version 1.0.1. That file may have some code dependent on some deprecated / moved code that is causing python.exe to crash.

A quick look at files in virtual environments present on my machines tells me:
for scrapy 0.24.4: this file is present
for scrapy 1.0.1: this file has been removed

This file being present in your scrapy 1.0.1 installation suggests that the installation might not have happened correctly. That, the file(s) from previous version are still lying around.

You might want to remove scrapy, delete the scrapy directory and reinstall.

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled and the first line of the output refering to deploy.py has diserpered but it still crashes. See answer above

Comment: Looks like you'll have to fire up the debugger and check it out step by step.